# Int32.Parse() VS Convert.ToInt32()?

Tags: c#

```
intID1 = Int32.Parse(myValue.ToString());
intID2 = Convert.ToInt32(myValue);
```

Which one is better and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.Net Parse versus Convert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465/net-parse-versus-convert)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

They are exactly the same, except that `Convert.ToInt32(null)` returns `0`.

`Convert.ToInt32` is defined as follows:

```
    public static int ToInt32(String value) {
        if (value == null) 
            return 0;
        return Int32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you find ToInt32() function source code?  I googled MSDN and can't find the details like you input. :-)

Comment: @Nano: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Common_Language_Infrastructure

Answer (score 6):

Well, Reflector says...

```cs
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}

public static int Parse(string s)
{
    return Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

So they're basically the same except that `Convert.ToInt32()` does an added null check.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "better" because "better" is subjective.

For instance - code readability. Some people prefer to see "Convert" in their code; others prefer to see "Parse".

In terms of speed, they're also both roughly equal [according to these benchmarks](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/convertto-vs-parse).

Or do you always wants a value returned? As others have mentioned, ConvertTo returns a 0 (zero) for null values whereas you don't get that option with Parse.